# Room table with 2 entity and 1 junction (Bridge) entity in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have made 2 table like this one:

**Product :**

| id | name | bio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fleur | True |
| 1 | Orange | False |

**Category :**

| id | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | first | Blue |
| 1 | second | Green |

And here is my Junction Table

**ProductCategoryCrossRef :**

| id | product_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

In my code the problem is that, the product is correctly fetchedm but the category not i don't know where is the problem.

Here is my data classes ->

```kotlin
data class ProductWithCategory (
    @Embedded val product: Product,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(ProductCategoryCrossRef::class)
    )
    val category: Category?
)
```

```
@Entity("product_with_category")
data class ProductCategoryCrossRef (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id") val productId: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id") val categoryId: Int = 0
)
```

Ps : Sometime, if an category is deleted, the product will have no category so no row in **product_with_category** table (ProductCategoryCrossRef).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In the Junction Function, you need to put the same **parentId** and **entityId** as the one in the **@Relation** function.

So for the example that'll be :

```
data class ProductWithCategory (
    @Embedded val product: Product,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            ProductCategoryCrossRef::class,
            "product_id",
            "category_id"
        )
    )
    val category: Category?
)
```